# Is it possible to check whether application can create file or not?

Tags: java, file

I am taking path from user.I want to validate that path like my program is able to create file on given location but the constraint is to perform validation I can't create file at that location.

File creation can failed for various reasons like

1. File is already exists.
2. Application does not have permission to create file
3. Memory issue.

Is this possible to check this without creating file.

Comment: Creating a file is IO. IO *always* has the opportunity to fail. There's no way to predict what the state of the filesystem will be when you attempt to modify it at some point in the future.

Comment: Of the heuristics I see in the answers so far, I see one glaring omission: In addition to lack of disk space availability, file creation can also fail due to lack of inode availability.

Comment: Or that the hard drive or indeed the universe exploded. The problem with all pre-checking is that it is nothing more than fortune-telling. Even if you test all the right things, they can change, and if you test the wrong things you can give the wrong answer.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun That question is just concerned with whether or not the path will be valid, not so much with the other concerns like if you have sufficient rights.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: This part of the question "I want to validate that path like my program __is able to create file on given location__" (emphasis mine) and this part "Application does not have __permission to create file__" (emphasis mine) suggest that Darshan Patel's question is indeed about creating a file, given the current file permissions.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Yes, and the question you suggested as a duplicate is not really concerned with access rights, just with valid paths.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Ah, I see, the other way around. You are right, I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no.

The answer to any question of this form is to perform the actual operation and handle the error that results, if any.

Trying to *predict* whether it will succeed is nothing more than fortune-telling.

And you still have to write the error-handling code anyway.

Comment: "... any question..." - you could check before that you can create the file before you compute the content/ask user for input to make things faster/more pleasant to user. Of course it's not 100% realiable. Btw. I didn't downvote you, your answer is still good (especially after the edit).

Comment: You can indeed, and if the situation changes between the test and the creation you will get the wrong answer, and you still have to write error-handling code, so why not avoid the guesswork and write something that *is* 100% reliable?

Answer (score 3):

File provide most of the functions see the below example

```
File file = new File("c:\\myfile.txt");
System.out.println("Does file exist "+file.exists());
if(!file.exists())
    file.createNewFile();
System.out.println("Can Read " + file.canRead());
System.out.println("Can Write " + file.canWrite());
System.out.println("Can Execute " + file.canExecute());
System.out.println(file.getFreeSpace());
```

But without file creation I don't think you could see file permissions directly.

but mostly you only can create a file if you have permission on that file directory so you can check permission on that file directory. And if permission exist than you can create file inside that directory.

```
File dir = file.getParentFile();    
System.out.println("Can Read " + dir.canRead());
System.out.println("Can Write " + dir.canWrite());
System.out.println("Can Execute " + dir.canExecute());      
System.out.println(dir.getFreeSpace());
```

Comment: Assumes nothing changes between the test and the creation. Fortune-telling.

Comment: @EJP I am agreed with your point that user must use exceptions properly  instead of rely on such checks but if someone want to do pre-check than what is the option? If something changed in between than user must handle error scenario but here question is just about the pre-checks. Non of the fortune teller are 100% accurate :P ....

Comment: If someone wants to do a pre-check then they don't understand causality. The fact that fortune-telling isn't accurate *is my point.* Don't attempt it and you can't be wrong.

Comment: Might be .. I could not fortune tell that why user asked this question. He might get a technical requirement from a non technical client.

Comment: There is no 'might be' about it whatsoever. It can't be done. Period. If that's what his client asked for, which isn't stated anywhere, he has to educate the client. That's all part of being a professional. A non-technical patient could tell his doctor that his requirement is to live for 200 years, but that's not what he's going to get. Expecting the impossible isn't rational, and neither is trying to implement it.

Comment: @EJP ... Nice conversation ... gave up from my side. see you on some other post.

Comment: "And if permission exist than you can create file inside that directory."  Not if the filesystem is mounted read-only.  The **only** way to test if action X can work is to **do** action X - whatever X is.  Trying to do otherwise will result in incorrect predictions while also creating the possibility of security-exploitable race conditions.

Comment: So someone has mounted readonly filesystem on a directory than what the dir.canWrite() will return ???? I think 'false' and user will able to know that this directory is not writable. Again .. I am fully agree with your line "The only way to test if action X can work is to do action X" .... but my earlier answer was just for a formal precheck if someone wants to do.